# select dropdown interval time from my DB - php sql

Tags: php, sql

I need to select dropdown from my database (time interval) and i stucked on submit button, can you help me please?

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die("Connection Failed");
    mysql_select_db("db")or die("Connection Failed");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $result1= mysql_query($query);

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <select>
        <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>    
            <option value="<?php echo $line['register_date'];?>"><?php echo $line['register_date'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <select>
        <?php while ($line2 = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $line2['register_date'];?>"><?php echo $line2['register_date'];?></option><?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="get graph">
</form>

<?php 
    $sql_graph="select * from tbl where register_date>='$line' and register_date<='line2'";
    $ress=mysql_query($sql_graph);
?>
```

**my table structure will be :**

```
mysql> select * from table_name;
+-----+-------+-----------+---------+---------------+
| id  | hours | item1     | item2   | register_date |
+-----+-------+-----------+---------+---------------+
| 44  | 23:55 | 511657    | 565553  | 2015-09-30    |
| 48  | 01:55 | 444657    | 144553  | 2015-10-01    |
| 49  | 02:55 | 2214657   | 144553  | 2015-10-01    |
| 50  | 03:55 | 1114657   | 224553  | 2015-10-01    |
| 51  | 04:55 | 414657    | 24553   | 2015-10-01    |
| 52  | 04:58 | 414655437 | 2453253 | 2015-10-01    |
| 53  | 04:59 | 55437     | 24553   | 2015-10-01    |
```

Can you help me please?

---

If I want to select  interval  from column 'register_date'.

2015-09-30 => 2015-10-01 and output all the column in sql query?

Example in the following link..my "project"
http://54.187.150.122/php/index3.php

Comment: All `mysql_` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli` or `PDO::MySQL`. What exactly is your problem? 'stuck on submit' is not very explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assigned name for your select element so you wouldn't be able to post the values. Use like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="register1">
        <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>    
            <option value="<?php echo $line['register_date'];?>"><?php echo $line['register_date'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <select name="register2">
        <?php while ($line2 = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $line2['register_date'];?>"><?php echo $line2['register_date'];?></option><?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="get graph">
</form>
```

And as @Tom Regner says, mysqli is deprecated, use mysli or PDOs

Comment: Just a small extension of the response:

Your query will not work.

You should  check if $_POST, filter your post vars and then use the post values in the query

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code .. thanks for help! It's 100% functional!

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "user_sql", "pass_sql");
$db_select= mysql_select_db('db_name', $con);
$query="select * from tbl_name";
if ( !$con){
die('error: ' . mysql_error());
}
$result = mysql_query($query, $con);
$result1= mysql_query($query, $con);
?>
<form action="script.php" method="POST">
<select name="register">
<?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $line['id'];?>"><?php echo $line['id'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
 </select>
<select name="register1">
<?php while ($line2 = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $line2['id'];?>"><?php echo $line2['id'];?></option><?php } ?>
 </select>

<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$query_graph="select * from tbl_name where id>='".$_POST['register']."' and id<='".$_POST['register1']."' ";
$result2= mysql_query($query_graph, $con);

echo "<table>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
                echo "<tr><td>". $row['id'] ."</td>";
                echo "<td>". $row['hours'] ."</td>";
                echo "<td>". $row['node1'] ."</td>";
                echo "<td>". $row['node2'] ."</td>";
                echo "<td>". $row['register_date'] ."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
}
?>
```